# repeating array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem that doesn't let me continue my work, and my problem is to make an array always repeat. Here is my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("color 0B");
    char huruf[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}, a;
    int i, x;
    cout << "\n\nInput a character : ";
    cin >> a;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        if (huruf[i] == a)
            x = 1;
        if (x == 1)
            cout << "THERE IS";
        else
            cout << "THERE IS NO";
}
```

I want the `Input a Character :` always repeat itself, so I can input the character so many times.

Comment: If you are learning you should use only standard headers.

Comment: You should nearly always use `{}` with loops. Only the first `if` statement is controlled by your `for` loop, and I can't easily tell if that's intentional or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a loop
below example, hitting "enter" gets you out of loop

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        system("color 0B");
        char huruf[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}, a;
        int i, x;
        do
    {
        x = 0;
        cout << "\n\nInput a character : ";
        cin >> a;
        for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
            if (huruf[i] == a)
                x = 1;
            if (x == 1)
                cout << "THERE IS";
            else
                cout << "THERE IS NO";
    } while (a != '\n');
  }
```

Comment: there is an error while compiling it, it says  no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'char')

Comment: try now.. fixed to check for 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to use a "while" loop.

So you would add something like this to your program:

```
bool choice = true;
while (choice)
{
    [stuff you want to repeat]
    std::cout << "Do you want to enter another character? Enter 1 for yes or 2 for no." << endl;
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    if (num == 2)
    {
        choice = false;
    }
}
```

Alternately you could change it a little to make it less cumbersome:

```
int main()
{
    system("color 0B");
    char huruf[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}, a;
    int i, x;
    bool choice = true;
    while (choice)
    {
        cout << "\n\nInput a character, or -1 to quit: ";
        cin >> a;
        if (a == -1)
        {
            choice = false;
        }
        for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
            if (huruf[i] == a)
                x = 1;
            if (x == 1)
                cout << "THERE IS";
            else
                cout << "THERE IS NO";
    }
}
```

Comment: `choice` should ideally be `bool`, although in this case it's an infinite loop so you could just use `while (true)` or `for (;;)`

Comment: @NeilKirk I changed choice to a bool as suggested but which loop is infinite and how so?

Comment: Now that you modify `choice` it is no longer :) But the loop won't exit immediately when `choice` becomes `false`. Was that intentional?

Comment: I had a feeling it was so. I wasn't sure exactly what OP was trying to accomplish so I left it there, but if they wanted OP could have it quit when -1 is answered using return 0, no?

Comment: Yes he could return. But what I meant before by "infinite loop" (which it isn't really as it can end, sorry if I confused you), is that you don't need to bother with a dummy `choice` variable at all if you will manually end the loop inside.

Comment: This is true, it's more a habit for me at this point just to do the framework that way and leave it- it's not really going to change your efficiency 99% of the time and it's just how I learned it. Can always improve, though, so thanks for the input!